# Python's __loader__, what is it?

Tags: python, loader, python-import

I've seen the term `__loader__` floating around some Python files and I can't find any documentation on it aside from a few brief descriptions about it's purpose, but they still don't provide enough information for me to get a good understanding of it. All I know is that it has something to do with importing modules, other than that I'm completely at a loss. What does it do? When is it used? How can I use it if at all?

Comment: I dunno ... where have you seen it? this is the first ive ever seen something like that ...

Comment: I saw it in the built-in module `linecache`, which I in turn saw from `traceback`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> What is `__loader__`?

`__loader__` is an attribute that is set on an imported module by its loader.  Accessing it should return the loader object itself.

In Python versions before 3.3, `__loader__` was not set by the built-in import machinery.   Instead, this attribute was only available on modules that were imported using a custom loader.

However, this functionality changed in Python 3.3 because of [PEP 0302](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/).  Now, `__loader__` is available on every module that is imported:

```
>>> # Python 3.3 interpreter
>>> import os
>>> os.__loader__
<_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01F86370>
>>>
```

---

> What is a loader?

A [loader](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-loader) is an object that is returned by a finder. It uses its `load_module()` method to load a module into memory.  [`importlib.abc.Loader`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.Loader) is an example of an abstract base class for a loader.

---

> What is a finder?

A [finder](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-finder) is an object that uses its `find_module()` method to try and find the loader for a module.  [`importlib.abc.Finder`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.Finder) is an example of an abstract base class for a finder.  Note however that it is deprecated in favor of [`importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder) and [`importlib.abc.PathEntryFinder`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.PathEntryFinder).

---

> How can I use it, if at all?

The main use of `__loader__` is for introspection.  However, there are two other common uses:

1. `__loader__` may be used to gather data on a specific module's loader.
2. In Python versions before 3.3, `__loader__` could be used with `hasattr` to check whether or not a module was imported with the built-in import machinery:

   ```
   >>> # Python 3.2 interpreter
   >>> import os
   >>> hasattr(os, '__loader__')
   False
   >>>
   ```

   If `hasattr(os, '__loader__')` had returned `True`, it would mean that the `os` module was imported using a custom loader.  Since it did not, it means that the module was imported using the built-in import machinery.

   *Note:* The above test will not work in Python 3.3+ because of the changes made by PEP 0302.