# What is happening in m5/objects/__init__.py file gem5

Tags: python, gem5

I am new with gem5 simulator. I was reading the documentation (http://www.m5sim.org/Configuration_/_Simulation_Scripts) trying to understand how everything is implemented. When they write about Python classes they say the following:

> gem5 provides a collection of Python object classes that correspond to its C++ simulation object classes. These Python classes are defined in a Python module called "m5.objects". The Python class definitions for these objects can be found in .py files in src, typically in the same directory as their C++ definitions.

> To make the Python classes visible, the configuration file must first import the class definitions from the m5 module

In the m5/objects directory there is only one file "__init__.py". This is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

from m5.internal import params
from m5.SimObject import *

try:
    modules = __loader__.modules
except NameError:
    modules = { }

for module in modules.keys():
    if module.startswith('m5.objects.'):
        exec("from %s import *" % module)
```

Normally I don't program with Python so perhaps that is the problem, but I haven't fully understood what is going on here. In this other post [Python's __loader__, what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185888/pythons-loader-what-is-it)  they speak about what **loader** means but I feel I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but putting prints everywhere would likely explain a lot :-) But maybe more importantly, is there an end goal for understand this, and if so what is it?

Comment: I was just trying to understand why is so important that this file is included in all SimObjects. I guess the end goal is just my curiosity :-). Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The `__loader__`

Consider the following code:

```
import sys
class FooImporter:
    def find_module(self, module_name, package_path):
        return self if module_name == 'foo' else None

    def load_module(self, module_name):
        print('FooImporter is working.')
        sys.modules[module_name] = __import__('sys')

# This activates the importer
sys.meta_path.append(FooImporter())
# This should trigger our importer to import 'foo'
import foo
# Show what we've just got
print(foo)
```

This will result in output:

```
FooImporter is working.
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

As long as you do not have a python module named `foo` in `PYTHONPATH`.

Python Import Hook ([PEP 302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/)) allows us to customize the behavior of `import`. In the above example, module `foo` was said to be found and handled by the `FooImporter`. Note the importer will create the module `foo` as an alias of `sys`. The complete importer (unlike the simplified one we've seen) will be responsible for setting the `__loader__` attribute for the imported module to the importer itself.

### Gem5's import hook

Back to your question, gem5 is using the same mechanism for loading `SimObject`'s by its design of modulization. You can find the very importer class at `src/python/importer.py` with the class name `CodeImporter`.

When the module `m5.object` was being imported, say,

```
from m5.objects import Root
```

The `CodeImporter` will be responsible for handling the import task, in which the `__loader__` attribute will be set for the imported module (in this case `m5.objects`). If you try printing `__loader__` in `m5/objects/__init__.py`, you'll get something like:

```
<importer.CodeImporter object at 0x7f4f58941d60>
```

The `__loader__.modules` is a dictionary containing gem5 maintained `SimObjects` where each item will be added by `addModule()` calls from `src/sim/init.cc`.

As long as a `SimObject`'s C++ correspondence has called the constructor for `EmbeddedPython`, it will be added to a list so the gem5 initialization will remember to add it to the instance of `CodeImporter`. For example, one should be able to find a `Root.py.cc` file in the build folder that registers the `Root` object. The loop at the end of `m5/object/__init__.py` is just importing a list of known `SimObject`'s by this mechanism.

I think this should be sufficient to give someone a picture of the underlying magic and (hopefully) resolve their curiosity.