# How to call a python function from C++ with pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api, pybind11

Please consider the following C++ pybind11 program:

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

int main() {
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

    py::dict locals;

    py::exec(R"(

        import sys

        def f():
            print(sys.version)

    )", py::globals(), locals);

    locals["f"]();  // <-- ERROR
}
```

The `py::exec` call and the enclosed `import sys` call both succeed, but the call `locals["f"]()` throws an exception:

```
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

on the first line of function `f`.

Expected behaviour is that the program prints the python system version.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I modified the program as suggested by @DavidW:

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

int main() {
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

    py::dict globals = py::globals();

    py::exec(R"(

        import sys

        def f():
            print(sys.version)

    )", globals, globals);

    globals["f"]();  // <-- WORKS NOW
}
```

and it now works.

I'm not 100% sure I understand what is going on, so I would appreciate an explanation.

(In particular does the modification of the common `globals` / `locals` dictionary impact any other scripts.  Is there some global dictionary that is part of the python interpreter that the `exec` script is modifying?  or does `py::globals()` take a copy of that state so the execed script is isolated from other scripts?)

**Update 2**:

So it looks like having globals and locals be the same dictionary is the default state:

```
$ python
>>> globals() == locals()
True
>>> from __main__ import __dict__ as x
>>> x == globals()
True
>>> x == locals()
True
```

...and that the default value for the two is `__main__.__dict__`, whatever that is (`__main__.__dict__` is the dictionary returned by `py::globals()`)

I'm still not clear what exactly `__main__.__dict__` is.

Comment: I think that if `globals != locals` for `exec` then it's executed as if it's in a class scope (and lookup to `sys` defined in the outer scope couldn't work).

Comment: @DavidW: So I should pass the same `py::dict` to both globals and locals?

Comment: I think so (but not in a position to test it right now, otherwise I'd post it as an answer)

Comment: @DavidW: Ok I tried it and it works, I'll add update and follow up question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the initial problem (solved in the comments) was that having different globals and locals causes it to be evaluated as if it were in a class (see [the Python documentation for `exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) - the PyBind11 function behaves basically the same):

> Remember that at the module level, globals and locals are the same dictionary. If exec gets two separate objects as globals and locals, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition.

A function scope doesn't look up variables defined in its enclosing class - this wouldn't work

```
class C:
    import sys
    def f():
        print(sys.version)
        # but C.sys.version would work
```

and thus your code doesn't work.

---

`pybind11::globals` returns a dictionary [that's shared in a number of places](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=globals#_CPPv47globalsv):

> Return a dictionary representing the global variables in the current execution frame, or `__main__.__dict__` if there is no frame (usually when the interpreter is embedded).

and thus any modifications to this dictionary will be persistent and stay (which probably isn't what you want!). In your case it's probably `__main__.__dict__` but in general "the current execution frame" might change from call-to-call, depending on how much you're crossing the C++-Python boundary. For example, if a Python function calls a C++ function that modifies `globals()` then exactly what you modify depends on the caller.

My advice would be to create a new, empty `dict` instead and pass that to `exec`. This ensures that you run in a fresh, non-shared namespace.

---

`__main__` is just a [special module that represents the "top level code environment"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html). Like any module is has a `__dict__`. When running in the REPL it's the global scope there. From the `pybind11` point of view it's just a module with a dict, and you probably shouldn't be writing into it casually (unless you've really decided that you want to deliberately put something there to share it globally).

---

Regarding the `__builtins__`: the documentation for the Python `exec` function says

> If the globals dictionary does not contain a value for the key `__builtins__`, a reference to the dictionary of the built-in module builtins is inserted under that key. That way you can control what builtins are available to the executed code by inserting your own `__builtins__` dictionary into globals before passing it to `exec()`.

and looking at the code for the `PyRun_String` that Pybind11 `exec` calls, the same applies there.

This dictionary seems to be sufficient for the builtin functions to be looked up correctly. (If that isn't the case then you can always do `pybind11::dict(pybind11::module::import("builtins").attr("__dict__"))` to make a copy of the builtin dict and use that instead. However, I don't believe it's necessary)

Comment: If I create an empty dict won't it be missing all the builtins (`print` etc) ?

Comment: I believe not (see the edit). However I haven't actually tested it from PyBind11 itself (so there's a little uncertainty)

Comment: The default globals dict (`__main__.__dict__`) for a python intepretter seems to have the following items: `__name__`, `__doc__`, `__package__`, `__loader__`, `__spec__`, `__annotations__`, `__builtins__`, whereas when I exec with an empty globals dict it contains only `__builtins__`.  I wonder if the absence of any of those other global dict entries has any observable effect (in particular `__loader__` catches my eye).

Comment: `__loader__` (and `__spec__` I think) have to do with what was used to load the module (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185888/pythons-loader-what-is-it). I don't think it will be missed in the vast majority of cases.